# PHP files open while clicking on send

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

this is my code in HTML5
    whenever i am clicking on send button ...
    phpfiles open rather mailing on that mail id which I mentioned can anybody help me out please ???

```
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="alert alert-success hidden" id="contactSuccess">
  <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent to us.</div>
  <div class="alert alert-danger hidden" id="contactError">
  <strong>Error!</strong> There was an error sending your message.</div>
  <h2 class="short">
  <strong>Contact</strong> Us</h2>
  <form action="php/contact-form.php" id="contactForm" type="post">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Your name *</label> 
        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100" class="form-control"
        name="name" id="name" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <label>Your email address *</label> 
        <input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address."
        data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email"
        id="email" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Subject</label> 
        <input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter the subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control"
        name="subject" id="subject" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-12">
        <label>Message *</label> 
        <textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="10" class="form-control" name="message"
        id="message"></textarea></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading..." />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
======================================================
```

and dis are my codes in php file...

```
<?php
session_cache_limiter('nocache');
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('r', 0));

header('Content-type: application/json');

// Enter your email address below.
$to = 'info@webppulse.com';

$subject = $_POST['subject'];

if($to) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $fields = array(
        0 => array(
            'text' => 'Name',
            'val' => $_POST['name']
        ),
        1 => array(
            'text' => 'Email address',
            'val' => $_POST['email']
        ),
        2 => array(
            'text' => 'Message',
            'val' => $_POST['message']
        )
    );

    $message = "";

    foreach($fields as $field) {
        $message .= $field['text'].": " . htmlspecialchars($field['val'], ENT_QUOTES) . "<br>\n";
    }

    $headers = '';
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " .  $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";

    if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'success');
    } else{
        $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    }

    echo json_encode($arrResult);

} else {

    $arrResult = array ('response'=>'error');
    echo json_encode($arrResult);

}
?>
```

whenever i am clicking on send button ...
phpfiles open rather mailing on that mail id can someone help me out please ?

Comment: Where do you run this code? Is PHP installed/enabled and running properly?

Comment: @djot: is right. Please check PHP is installed or not.

Comment: YES PHP IS INSTALLED I M RUNNING THIS CODE THRUGH WAMP SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Change the following code

```
<form action="php/contact-form.php" id="contactForm" type="post">
```

with

```
<form action="php/contact-form.php" id="contactForm" method="post">
```

Comment: The code is copied from somewhere anyway ... so `method` should be the default if missing ... and working.

Comment: I Purchased a template in that conct form was there its not working

Answer (score 0):

You Must have install localhost server Like xampp or wampp.
Then put files in
For Xampp : **htdocx/** Put your file in htdocx folder and run.
Foe wampp: **www/** put your file in www folder and run.

Comment: sir i did this using xampp

Comment: Open xampp control pannel and check Apache & MySql Server is running or not?
still showing PHP code on page submit?

Answer (score 0):

Turn your type="post" into a method="post". Also, you need to have your project placed into the htdocs folder of your WAMP directory and ensure that the WAMP server has been turned on.

You should always try a "Hello World" test first to ensure that everything is running correctly. Check out tutorials on the Web for this.

Comment: Turn your type="post" into a method="post".  still the same as it is

Comment: Is your project definitely in the htdocs folder inside the WAMP directory? And is WAMP definitely turned on?

Comment: sir i did this using xampp offcourse yes sir....
and placed all the files in same Xampp : htdocx/ folder...

Comment: still its not working so i got confused one mistek was about type to method i changed but still the major thing is it is showing me php files ....

Comment: I'm just asking from experience, I have made php files outside of the htdocs before and wondered why they kept being downloaded. What about in the browser? Are you going to http://localhost/foldername/filename?

Comment: And that's where you are going to test out your form? To test php you ALWAYS need to go to localhost/foldername/filename say you had a project folder called formtest and the file with the form was index.html or index.php then you would go to localhost/formtest/index.html or localhost/formtest/index.php.

Comment: i followed all procedure again from putting files again into wamp folder now bingo i got another error i ll be helpfull if u solved it....

Comment: can i get ur mail id so i can send u d error ...in commnt we cant write the erorr is too long

Comment: I would suggest just Googling around and try to find the error. Usually you can just copy and paste a snippet to get an idea. Sorry, but I really don't want to give out my email address.

Comment: ok i will post another eoplease give ur valubale suggetion on ror on same starkflow can u that